# Nginx x_forwarded_for get double ip address

Tags: nginx

When i used nginx `$http_x_forwarded_for` to get user **real_IP**, but sometime, i found the realIP is double from access.log, like:`"223.8.37.61, 123.151.77.70".`
why?

Comment: Multiple IPs is expected behavior. Look at this discussion.
https://serverfault.com/questions/846489/can-x-forwarded-for-contain-multiple-ips

Answer (score 0):

The `X-Forwarded-For` header contains a list of IP addresses. Use the realip module to parse the header to extract the client's IP address.

For example:

```
set_real_ip_from  192.168.1.1;
real_ip_header    X-Forwarded-For;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html) for more.

Comment: yes, you are right, but the `$http_x_forwarded_for` get first IP by default, it is client's IP i think. if  `$http_x_forwarded_for` has double IP, i think current request is abnormally.